# Getting hex colours from a image

Tags: time-limit-exceeded, image, angular.js, clustering, typescript

I am trying to get the hex colours from an image. The problem I am having is that for some reason randomly the code causes high CPU usage, which times out the browser and I am not sure how to optimise the code. I am not sure where the high CPU usage is. I've tried adding delays using `setTimeout()` but with no luck.

The code was original written in Javascript but I am converted it to Typescript,

Here is full code code which returns the hex values

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ExtractColours {

  private euclidean(p1, p2) {
    let s = 0;
    for (let i = 0, l = p1.length; i < l; i++) {
      s += Math.pow(p1[i] - p2[i], 2)
    }
    return Math.sqrt(s);
  }

  private calculateCenter(points, n) {
    let vals = [];
    let plen = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) { vals.push(0); }
    for (let i = 0, l = points.length; i < l; i++) {
      plen++;
      for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        vals[j] += points[i][j];
      }
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      vals[i] = vals[i] / plen;
    }
    return vals;
  }


private kmeans(points, k, min_diff) {

        let plen = points.length;
        let clusters = [];
        let seen = [];

        while (clusters.length < k) {
          let idx = parseInt(String(Math.random() * plen));
          let found = false;
          for (let i = 0; i < seen.length; i++ ) {
            if (idx === seen[i]) {
              found = true;
              break;
            }
          }
          if (!found) {
            seen.push(idx);
            clusters.push([points[idx], [points[idx]]]);
          }
        }

        while (true) {
          let  plists = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            plists.push([]);
          }

          for (let j = 0; j < plen; j++) {
            let p = points[j];
            let smallest_distance = 10000000;
            let idx = 0;

            for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
              let distance = this.euclidean(p, clusters[i][0]);
              if (distance < smallest_distance) {
                smallest_distance = distance;
                idx = i;
              }
            }
            plists[idx].push(p);
          }

          let diff = 0;

          for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            let old = clusters[i];
            let list = plists[i];
            let center = this.calculateCenter(plists[i], 3);
            let dist = this.euclidean(old[0], center);
            clusters[i] = [center, (plists[i])];
            diff = diff > dist ? diff : dist;
          }
          if (diff < min_diff) {
            break;
          }
        }

        return clusters;
      }
```

here I am converting the rgb to hex but I am also returning the alpha value

```
private rgbToHex(rgb) {

          function th(i) {
            let h = parseInt(i).toString(16);
            return h.length == 1 ? '0'+h : h;
          }

          let alpha = (parseInt(th(rgb[0]),16) + parseInt(th(rgb[1]),16) + parseInt(th(rgb[2]),16)) / 3;

        return parseInt(String(alpha)).toString(16) +'#' + th(rgb[0]) + th(rgb[1]) + th(rgb[2]) ;
      }


      public process_image(img, ctx) {
        let points = [];

        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 200, 200);

        let data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 200, 200).data;

        for (let i = 0, l = data.length; i < l;  i += 4) {
          let r = data[i];
          let g = data[i+1];
          let b = data[i+2];
          points.push([r, g, b]);
        }
        let results = this.kmeans(points, 3, 1);
        let hex = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          hex.push(this.rgbToHex(results[i][0]));
        }

        return hex;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### General feedback

There are a few ways that some of the loops can be simplified (see below). These may or may not improve the high CPU issue.

The code makes some repeated calls to functions with the same values in close proximity (e.g. calling `th()` with each value of `rgb` twice in `rgbToHex()`). Storing the returned values and re-using the stored values would make the code more efficient.

I'd consider suggesting the use of functional approaches (E.g. with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)) but I wouldn't in this case, given that execution time is an issue.

### Targeted feedback

There are some places where `const` could be used for any variable that doesn't get re-assigned - e.g. `vals` in `ExtractColours::calculateCenter()`, `plen` in `ExtractColours::kmeans()`, etc. This avoid unintentional re-assignment.

---

There are places where `parseInt()` is called without a radix - e.g.

> ```
> let idx = parseInt(String(Math.random() * plen));
> ```

and

> ```
> let h = parseInt(i).toString(16);
> ```

The radix should always be specified<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix)</sup> because it doesn't always default to 10.

---

Let's look at that method `ExtractColours::calculateCenter()`. The variable `plen` could be assigned to `points.length` (like it is in `ExtractColours::kmeans()`), instead of incrementing that in the second `for` loop. And then the division of each array element by `plen` could be moved into the previous `for` loop.

And `vals` is declared and assigned like this:

> ```
> let vals = [];
> let plen = 0;
>
> for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) { vals.push(0); }
> ```

This could be simplified using [`Array.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

```
const vals = Array(n).fill(0);
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix</sub>